# System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper Null Reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I get the following error randomly when running an ASP.NET MVC 2 project.  This error occurs on different pages at different times.  Cannot reproduce this error or identify pattern of when and on which page the error occurs.

```
System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper  ---> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It happens on different pages

Example:  (Trying to view a partial view)

```
System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'. ---> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ASP.views_shared_searchcontrol_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Another Example (While building sitemap, sitemap code omitted)

```
System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'. ---> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at ASP.views_shared_site_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
```

Comment: You've just asked "Why am I getting a null reference exception?" without giving us anything to go on. Can you please give us some code? `SearchControl.ascx` and `Site.Master` would be helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem. For me it turned out I had strongly typed my master page to be of a certain type and in some scenarios I was returning a model that was not of that type and that is what was causing this error.

Comment: so this error happens on every page that use that master page and is not of that type right??